# Huge UI elements in Crunchbang

Tags: linux, drivers, crunchbang, user-interface, graphic-card

I have just installed Crunchbang on my Desktop, and windows and menus appear incredibly enlarged. When I right click the context menu fills the screen, for example.

My graphics card is the Radeon HD 7790. I'm sure this has something to do with AMD's shitty Linux support. I have the OS installed on a partition on an external HDD, so I booted the same install up on my Intel HD 4000 laptop and did not get this problem. I installed `fglrx-driver` through `apt` while it was booted on my laptop, but when I loaded it on the desktop this problem persisted.

I managed to open a terminal on the desktop, and—with great difficulty—ran `xrandr`, which said it was running at a 1280x720 resolution (My monitor is 1080p). when I ran `aticonfig --initial` on the desktop it said it could not find a supported connector.

[image: Picture of monitor]